# Simple animation of 2D coordinates using matplotlib and pyplot

Tags: python, animation, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib. I have a list of x-y coordinates that I update in python and want to animate using matplotlib's pyplot. I want to specify the x-range and y-range in advance. Below is my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[5,6,7,8]
for t in range(100):
    #lists x and y get updated here
    #...
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='None')
plt.show()
```

As you can see, I use `plt.plot()` and `plt.show()` *at the end of my iteration loop* to plot only the final coordinates. But I want to put this step *inside* the loop and plot at every iteration with a specified pause time so that I have an animation as the loop runs.

Just moving that statement inside the loop or tweaks thereabout aren't working.
I want to keep it very simple though, and don't want to use `matplotlib.animation`. Is there some simple method without using many more modules and libraries (only stuff like `plt.pause()` and perhaps only a bit more) that will let me do what I want?

I looked at many places online, and the problem I face with most methods there is that I am using python(x,y) (that's python version 2.7) on Windows for this, and animations using too complicated modules and libraries are crashing here.

However, I am able to run simple stuff like [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/animation/random_data.html) on the matplotlib site, which is close to what I want, but not quite. So perhaps the best thing will be a modification of this example that works for my case of 2D data (that example is for a 1D row). But any other suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is adapted from the [animation demo](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/animation_demo.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [5, 6, 7, 8]

for t in range(10):
    if t == 0:
        points, = ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='None')
        ax.set_xlim(0, 10) 
        ax.set_ylim(0, 10) 
    else:
        new_x = np.random.randint(10, size=5)
        new_y = np.random.randint(10, size=5)
        points.set_data(new_x, new_y)
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

While this is simple the docstring say that it is slow.

Comment: +1. This works. I'll just try to adapt it into my final program and see how that goes.

Comment: It may be convenient to use `ax.clear()`; then you can simply plot a fresh figure and you don't need to distinguish between first and later runs. Also, `plt.pause()` caused an error for me, I used `fig.canvas.start_event_loop()` instead.