# Change matplotlib.pyplot text() object properties

Tags: python, animation, plot, matplotlib

I have a `matplotlib.pyplot` graph that updates in a loop to create an animation, using this kind of code that I got from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10896688/711017):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
x = [1, 2, 3, 4] #x-coordinates
y = [5, 6, 7, 8] #y-coordinates

for t in range(10):
    if t == 0:
        points, = ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='None')
    else:
        new_x = ... # x updated
        new_y = ... # y updated
        points.set_data(new_x, new_y)
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

Now I want to put a `plt.text()` on the plot which will show the time that has passed. Putting a `plt.text()` statement inside the loop, however, creates a new `text` object at *every* iteration, putting them all on top of each other. So I must create only one `text` object at the first iteration, then modify it in subsequent iterations. Unfortunately, I cannot find in any documentation how to modify the properties of an instance of this object (it's a `matplotlib.text.Text` object) once it is created. Any help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Similar as `set_data` you can use `set_text` (see here for the documentation: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_text).

So first

```
text = plt.text(x, y, "Some text")
```

and then in the loop:

```
text.set_text("Some other text")
```

In your example it could look like:

```
for t in range(10):
    if t == 0:
        points, = ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='None')
        text = plt.text(1, 5, "Loops passed: 0")
    else:
        new_x = ... # x updated
        new_y = ... # y updated
        points.set_data(new_x, new_y)
        text.set_text("Loops passed: {0}".format(t))
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [5, 6, 7, 8]

for t in range(10):
    plt.cla()
    plt.text(4.6,6.7,t)
    x = np.random.randint(10, size=5)
    y = np.random.randint(10, size=5)

    points, = ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='None')
    ax.set_xlim(0, 10)     
    ax.set_ylim(0, 10) 
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

Notice the `plt.cla()` call. It clears the screen.

Comment: But notice I'm not replotting my data, only changing it. If we use `plt.cla()` here, it clears my plot too, and only the text persists.