# Matplotlib - 2 Figures in Subplot - 1 is Animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have two figures that I would like to plot in a subplot:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
```

Assume that ax1 is going to be populated with an animation which adds points ( a scatter plot).  Ax2 then bins these points to a meshgrid and displays the density.

Can I display the animation in subplot 1, and on completion add the density image to subplot2?

Comment: Yes, you can. Details would depend on what do you mean by 'completion'

Comment: The animation is driven by a yield statement.  Once the yield returns false (finished) I would like to have the adjacent figure appear / populate.  I can prerender the space, but not the plotted density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible. Please take a look at the [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html). You may also check the previous question:

[Simple animation of 2D coordinates using matplotlib and pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896054/simple-animation-of-2d-coordinates-using-matplotlib-and-pyplot)

Below is a sample implementation. The second plot is hidden until the first stops rendering:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update_line(num, data, line, img):
    line.set_data(data[...,:num])
    if num == 24:
        img.set_visible(True)
    return line, img

fig1 = plt.figure()

data = np.random.rand(2, 25)
ax1=plt.subplot(211)
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'rx')
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.title('test')
ax2=plt.subplot(212)
nhist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(data[0,:], data[1,:])
img = plt.imshow(nhist, aspect='auto', origin='lower')
img.set_visible(False)
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, 25, 
                                   fargs=(data, l, img),
                                   interval=50, blit=True)
line_ani.repeat = False
plt.show()
```

Comment: I need to delay generation of the second figure until the first has fully rendered.  Suggestions on how to control flow to do that?

Comment: @Jzl5325 I updated the answer wit a sample solution. It is not optimal, but as far as I know matplotlib does not trigger end animation events.

Comment: Interesting way to do it!  I was just trying the same idea using a thread and is_alive().  This looks like a simpler implementation.  Thanks!

Comment: What if you have an iterator function instead of an interval set?  Can you still return the img from the update_line?  I thought iterator needs to return a tuple of lines so not sure if I can make it work for me to update the axis text during blit.