# Matplotlib Subplot Animation with Basemap

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, subplot

I am trying to generate a four-panel animation of temperature change with time. Each of the four panels in the subplot should be an animated map; the difference between each panel being the data used. I have managed to generate the animation using one set of data (without subplots) with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

#dummy temperature data with 10 time-steps
y=np.random.randn(10, 60, 100) 

fig = plt.figure()
m = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0)
lats=np.linspace(90,-90,y.shape[1])
lons=np.linspace(-180,180,y.shape[2])
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,99.,30.), labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,60.), labels=[0,0,0,1])
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
m.pcolormesh(lons,lats,y[0],cmap=plt.cm.bwr, shading='flat',latlon=True)

def init():
    m                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

def animate(i):
    m.pcolormesh(lons,lats,y[i],cmap=plt.cm.bwr, shading='flat',latlon=True)
    return m

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=10, interval=100) #interval = number of milliseconds between frames                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

anim.save('movie.mp4')
```

I have looked at numerous examples ([1](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/subplots.html), [2](http://www.roboticslab.ca/matplotlib-animation/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366057/matplotlib-2-figures-in-subplot-1-is-animation)) of subplot animations, but still have no idea how to go about doing it with Basemap.

Comment: It would be a better question if you linked to one of the numerous examples you referred to. http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html?highlight=funcanimation#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation

Comment: Thanks for editing in the examples! And for accepting an answer. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your animation function needs to update four different maps in four separate axes within the figure.

- Create your four panels:

  ```
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
  ```

The axes are indexed. The way I suggested placing them in a 2x2 layout, they are indexed as a 2-d array, so reference the axes as `ax[0][0]`, `ax[0][1]`, `ax[1][0]`, and `ax[1][1]` when you create the maps.

- When you create your four instances of Basemap, assign each map to a different axes using the 
  `ax` parameter [(docs)](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/subplots.html#generating-the-subplots-at-the-beginning-with-plt-subplots).
- In your `animate` function, change the coloring of each axes. Assigning colors based on data to map `m_i` is with `m_i.pcolormesh` [(docs)](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.pcolormesh) as shown in your question.

Comment: Thanks BBrown. I've solved it with your help. For a two panel figure one would also adjust the 'init' function to:
    `def init():
        fig`

And adjust the animate function to:
    `def animate(i):
        m_a.pcolormesh(lons,lats,y[i],cmap=plt.cm.bwr, shading='flat',latlon=True)
        m_b.pcolormesh(lons,lats,y[i],cmap=plt.cm.bwr, shading='flat',latlon=True)
        return m_a, m_b`