# How to make an animation subplot with Matplotlib on Basemap?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to make a two-panel animation with time. I've found a similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458488/matplotlib-subplot-animation-with-basemap) that I want to do, but I cannot go through with. Here's my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

#dummy temperature data with 10 time-steps                                                     
y = np.random.randn(10, 60, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].set_title("aaaa")
m_a = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0)
lats = np.linspace(90,-90,y.shape[1])
lons = np.linspace(-180,180,y.shape[2])
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

m_a.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,99.,30.), labels=[1,0,0,0])
m_a.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,60.), labels=[0,0,0,1])
m_a.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
m_a.pcolormesh(lons,lats,y[0],cmap=plt.cm.bwr, shading='flat',latlon=True)

ax[1].set_title("bbbb")
m_b = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0)
lats = np.linspace(90,-90,y.shape[1])
lons = np.linspace(-180,180,y.shape[2])
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

m_b.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,99.,30.), labels=[1,0,0,0])
m_b.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,60.), labels=[0,0,0,1])
m_b.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
m_b.pcolormesh(lons,lats,y[0],cmap=plt.cm.bwr, shading='flat',latlon=True)


def init():
    fig

def animate(i):
    m_a.pcolormesh(lons,lats,y[i],cmap=plt.cm.bwr,shading='flat',latlon=True)
    m_b.pcolormesh(lons,lats,y[i],cmap=plt.cm.bwr,shading='flat',latlon=True)
    return m_a, m_b

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=10, interval=100) #interval = number of milliseconds between frames                                                      

plt.show()
```

However, the result animation is here⇒[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMxUK.png). Why is this happening? I'm glad if you review the code.

Comment: Why is *what* happening? What's the problem?

Comment: I wanted to make a two-panel animation subplot on Basemap. My code provides one animation plot on the right side of the figure, but it cannot provides the animation on the left side of the figure. This is the problem and I'd like to know how to fix it.

Comment: This comment is more informative than any of the text in the current question. Why not add it to the question instead of a comment?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you. I'll pay attention to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just forgot to specify the axes or the basemap to live in.

```
m_a = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0, ax=ax[0])
# ...
m_b = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0, ax=ax[1])
```

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEmes Thank you so much for helping me out. I could do that I wanted to.